# How to find all irreducible polynomials in Z2 with degree 5?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

I am totally lost on how to do this one. I am supposed to accomplish the following:

Find all irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ with degree $5$. 
I may use the fact that x, $x+1$ and $x^2+x+1$ are the irreducibles of degree less than or equal to 2

If someone could provide a step by step explanation of how to do this, that would be amazing! Thanks in advance!

P.S.: This is not a homework, but is a question on a past exam that I couldn't answer and I want to know how to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a rough procedure for finding all irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}_{2}[x]$. I will leave some of the details of computation to you.

If we let $f(x) = x^{5}+a_{4}x^{4}+a_{3}x^{3}+a_{2}x^{2}+a_{1}x+a_{0} \in \mathbb{Z}_{2}[x]$, we see that each $a_{i}$ can be $0$ or $1$, yielding two choices for each of the five coefficients. Hence, we note that there are $32$ polynomials of degree $5$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{2}[x]$.

Now, for $f(x)$ to be irreducible, it cannot be divisible by any polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_{2}[x]$ of degree $<5$. If a product of polynomials $\prod_{i} g_{i}(x)$ has degree $5$, then it follows that the degree of at least one $g_{i}(x) < 3$ (another way of saying this is that the any partition of $5$ into a sum of strictly positive integers contains a summand $ < 3$). Hence, it suffices to find all $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}_{2}[x]$ of degree $5$ such that no irreducible polynomial of degree $1$ or $2$ divides $f(x)$.

It is straightforward to test for division by the polynomials of degree $1$. We must ensure that our $f(x)$ does not have any roots in $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$. Simply take a test $f(x)$ and verify that $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ are nonzero. This narrows down our set of $16$ polynomials to our remaining possible choices. Call this remaining set $P$.

Now, to test for division by irreducible polynomials of degree $2$, we must first compute the irreducible polynomials of degree $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{2}[x]$. I leave this to you - comment if you need further help in this step. Once we have computed the irreducible polynomials of degree $2$, we can use simple polynomial long division (since $\mathbb{Z}_{2}[x]$ is a Euclidean domain!) to test each element of $P$ for divisibility by an irreducible polynomial of degree $2$. If $f(x) \in P$ is not divisible by any irreducible polynomial of degree $2$, it is an irreducible polynomial of degree $5$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{2}[x]$. I leave the details of these actual computations to you. Feel free to comment if you need further hints!

Comment: This is a fine answer, although paragraph 3's phrasing is kind of awkward, since $f$ can always decompose as a product of more than two irreducibles; it _is_ true that any reducible $f$ has _some_ decomposition into factors of degrees 1+4 or 2+3 (or more broadly, that it's divisible by some irreducible polynomial of degree 1 or 2), but I think there's a better way of making that argument than your current phrasing.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: great points, thanks! I'll try to edit it to something better. :)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: I've updated paragraph 3 in response to your suggestions. Hopefully it reads a bit more accurately (and smoothly!) now. Thanks again!

Comment: A good, generic way of doing this. You can generalize this to higher degrees by building a list of irreducibles as you go. Not unlike the sieve of Eratosthenes.

Comment: @AWertheim: I edited my questions since I left something out. Take a look and see if that changes anything about your answer.

Comment: @AWertheim: how do I compute the irreduciable polynominals of degree two in relation to my question?

Comment: @TheD3ac: I don't believe your edits change anything about my answer. As far as how to compute irreducible polynomials of degree two in $\mathbb{Z}_{2}[x]$, note that any reducible polynomial of degree $2$ must be divisible by a linear polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_{2}[x]$, hence must have a root in $\mathbb{Z}_{2}[x]$. The irreducibles of degree $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{2}[x]$ are therefore the degree $2$ polynomials with no roots in $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$. Hence, generate a list of the four possible degree $2$ polynomials, then plug in $0$ and $1$ to see if either is a root.

Comment: @AWertheim: Also, if we make the five coefficients in our f(x) zero, when we do f(0) won't we get zero out and thus f(x) has a root and thus the test of divisibility for polynominals of degree 1 will fail, correct?

Comment: @TheD3ac: if I understand what you mean, then indeed, $f(x) = x^{5}$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Z}_{2}[x]$.

Comment: @AWertheim: so doesn't this conflict with your part about testing for division by the polynomials of degree 1 since we should that f(x) has roots in Z2?

Comment: @TheD3ac: no. $f(x) = x^{5}$ contains a root in $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$, namely $0$. Hence, $x | f(x)$, and so $f(x) = x^{5} = x\cdot x^{4}$ is reducible. What part do you think is in conflict?

Comment: @AWertheim: the part where you say "We must ensure that our f(x) does not have any roots in ℤ2. Simply take a test f(x) and verify that f(0) and f(1) are nonzero" Doesn't finding that x^5 having a root in Z2 conflict this?

Comment: @TheD3ac: SOME polynomials of degree $5$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{2}[x]$ will have roots - these polynomials are reducible. One such polynomial is $x^{5}$. What you want to do is test each polynomial of degree $5$ and then ELIMINATE those with roots in $\mathbb{Z}_{2}[x]$ as reducible. There is no conflict here. Any irreducible polynomial of degree $5$ will not have a root in $\mathbb{Z}_{2}[x]$.

Comment: @AWertheim: Ah, okay, now I got it! Also, they only second degree irreducible polynominal that I could think of was x^2+x+1. Is that right?

Comment: @TheD3ac: glad to hear it! Yep, that's right :) (one can observe that $x^{2}, x^{2}+1, x^{2}+x$ each have roots in $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$).

Comment: @AWertheim: I got that the only first degree irreducible polynominal was x+1. Is that correct?

Comment: @TheD3ac: there are two first degree irreducible polynomials: $x$ and $x+1$.

Comment: @AWertheim: I got that the only polynominal in the set P 9 (after testing the divisibility of polynominals of degree 1) that you were talking about was x+1. Is that correct?

Answer (score 13):

Here's a different take. A bit ad hoc, but to an extent I expect that here. Also I will be using several bits and pieces of finite field theory.

**Claim 1.** $p_1(x)=p(x)=x^5+x^2+1$ is irreducible.

**Proof.** $p(0)=p(1)=1$ so it has no linear factors. That leaves the sole quadratic irreducible $x^2+x+1$ as a possibility. But $x^3+1=(x^2+x+1)(x+1)$, so
$$
p(x)=x^2(x^3+1)+1\equiv1\pmod{x^2+x+1}.
$$
Thus $p(x)$ has no factors of degree $\le2$. QED

**Corollary 1.** $p_2(x)=p(x+1)=(x+1)^5+(x+1)^2+1=x^5+x^4+x^2+x+1$ is irreducible.

**Proof.** A linear substitution takes an irreducible to an irreducible. QED

**Fun fact.** If $q(x)$ is irreducible with non-zero constant term(over any field), then so is its reciprocal polynomial
$$\tilde{q}(x)=x^{\deg q}q(\frac1x).$$

**Proof.** If we had $\tilde{q}(x)=g(x)h(x)$, it is an easy exercise to see that we would also have $q(x)=\tilde{g}(x)\tilde{h}(x)$. QED

Therefore
$$
p_3(x):=\tilde{p_1}(x)=x^5+x^3+1
$$
and
$$
p_4(x):=\tilde{p_2}(x)=x^5+x^4+x^3+x+1
$$
are also irreducible.

Going back to linear substitutions we see that
$$
p_5(x):=p_3(x+1)=x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+1
$$
is irreducible, and so is its reciprocal
$$
p_6(x):=\tilde{p_5}(x)=x^5+x^3+x^2+x+1
$$
which incidentally coincides with $p_4(x+1)$.

At this point we need another bit of theory. All these six polynomials have five zeros in the field $\Bbb{F}_{32}$, so between them they are minimal polynomials of all the thirty elements that are not in the prime field. Thus there are no others, and the list is complete.

---

I don't recall having done this exercise ever before, so thanks for letting me do it. I knew in advance that $p_1(x)$ is irreducible, because that occurs frequently enough.
I also knew that there would be exactly six irreducible quintics. I also knew that the substitutions $x\to 1/x$ and $x+1$ generate a group of six automorphisms of the rational function field. This time the stabilizer was trivial, so finding one irreducible produced all six.

Comment: Wow. This is a beautiful answer, with some really nice techniques I haven't seen before. Thanks for sharing. +1

Comment: Switching to CW, because I just found a dupe target. No more rep for me here.

Answer (score 4):

A straightforward inductive way to do this is to list all *reducible* polynomials of degree 5 and taking the complement set.

The list of reducible polynomials can be obtained by multiplying polynomials of degrees $a$ and $b$ such that $a+b=5$ in all the possible ways.

Since a polynomial will always factor into irreducibles, some shortcuts can be taken in the described strategy once you know the irreducible polynomials of degree $<5$.

Answer (score 4):

The following argument is specific to the question asked. Although I am
by no means a trained professional, please do not attempt this at home with
polynomials of larger degree.

The irreducible polynomial must be of the form
$x^5 + a_4x^4 + a_3x^3 + a_2x^2 + a_1x + 1$, that is, the degree-$5$ term
as well as the constant term must be nonzero. Of the $16$ possible
choices of $(a_4,a_3,a_2,a_1)$ we can eliminate the $8$ vectors of
*even* Hamming weight because the corresponding degree-$5$ polynomials 
have $1$ as a root. So, we are down to $8$ polynomials of which 
$6$ are necessarily
irreducible because the $30$ elements of $\mathbb F_{32}-\mathbb F_2$
all have order $31$ and come in sets of $5$ conjugates. Starting with
the lexicographically first polynomial $x^5 + x + 1$, we readily
discover via long division that
$$x^5 + x + 1 = (x^2+x+1)(x^3+x^2+1)$$ 
and so $x^5 + x + 1$ and its reciprocal $x^5+x^4+1 = (x^2+x+1)(x^3+x+1)$ 
are *reducible* polynomials. Thus, the irreducible polynomials of 
degree $5$ are
$$\begin{align}
x^5+x^2+1 &\quad x^5+x^3+1\\x^5+x^3+x^2+x+1 &\quad x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+1\\
x^5+x^4+x^2+x+1 &\quad x^5+x^4+x^3 + x + 1
\end{align}$$