# Is $X^5+...+1 \in \mathbb{F_2}[X]$ irreducible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

I am trying to determine if the following polynomials are irreducible in $\mathbb{F_2}[X]$ are irreducible:

> $f(X)=X^5+X^2+1$
>
> $g(X)=X^5+X^3+1$

There are no linear factors since $f(0)=f(1)=g(0)=g(1) \neq 0$

However there is another possible factorization: $(X^3+aX^2+bX+c)(X^2+dX+e)$

I am unsure how to verify if $f$ and $g$ can be factored in this way in $\mathbb{F_2}[X]$

Would appreciate your help on this one

Comment: Work out the product and impose the equality with $f$ or $g$ (the conditions are easily handled since you are on the field $\mathbb F_2$)

Comment: Ok so just expand in terms of $a$ and $b$ and see if they are equal to $f$ and $g$ using the fact that all coefficients are $0$ and $1$?

Comment: Well, your unknowns are $ a,b,c,d,e$. To start: note for example that you need $ce=1$ which implies $c=e=1$. Then work out the other conditions to have the equality of $(X^3+aX^2+bX+c)(X^2+dX+e)$ with $f$ or $g$.

Comment: Note that $g$ is reducible iff $f$ is reducible (as $g(X)=X^5\,f(1/X)$).  Thus, it suffices to check the reducibility of only one of them.

Comment: ok thanks. I am unsure about $f(1/X)$, how did you determine this? (what are the coefficents etc.?

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/998563/11619) is a relatively extensive discussion about various ways of finding all the irreducible quintics over $\Bbb{F}_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: find all irreducible polynomials of degree 2 (there are not many) and try to divide $f$ and $g$ by this (those) irreducible polynomial(s) of degree 2

Comment: Oh ok, so in this case irreducible polynomials of degree $2$ will not have linear factors.So $f(x)=x^2+ax+b$. $f(0)=b \neq 0 \implies b=1$. $f(1)=1+a+1 \neq 0 \implies 1+a+1=1 \implies a=-1$. So are the two irreducible polynomials: $x^2+x+1$ and $x^2-x+1$.. are these equal ?

Comment: Those are the same polynomial because $-1 \mod 2 = 1$.

Comment: Note: there are only an  irreducible polynomial of degre 2 in $F_2[X]$ is the  cyclotomic polynomial $ \Phi_3(X)$.

Answer (score 0):

From H. Potter's hint, it follows that $f(X)$ is reducible iff it is divisible by $X^2+X+1$.  Now, in the same spirit, $g(X)$ is reducible iff it is divisible by $X^2+X+1$ as well.  As $f(X)$ is reducible iff $g(X)$ is reducible, and $f(X)+g(X)=X^3+X^2=X^2(X+1)$ is not divisible by $X^2+X+1$, we conclude that $f(X)$ and $g(X)$ are irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Comment: How do you know that $f$ is irreducible iff $g$ is irreducible ?

Comment: Read my comment under the OP's question.