# How to find minimal polynomial for finite field

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, finite-fields

How can we find minimal polynomials for $\alpha $  in $GF(2^{n})$.
What is the general approach to find minimal polynomials. I know about minimal polynomials they are monic etc. In particular i want to know about primitive polynomials of $GF(32)$.

Comment: For irreducible polynomials of degree five specifically you can take a look at [this older question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/998563/11619). Many ways to find them all, as you see. Because $2^5-1=31$ is a prime, all the irreducible quintics are primitive (see also Dietrich Burde's answer).

Answer (score 2):

$GF(32)^\times$ is a group of order $31$ and so is cyclic.

You need to factor $x^{31}-1 \bmod 2$ and pick a factor of degree $5$.

$x^5+x^2+1$ is one such factor.

Comment: can u please describe in more detail , how do we factor $x^{31}-1 mod 2$?   and get the $\alpha : m_{1}(x) = x^{5}+x^{2}+1$

Comment: @BreezyBoo, you don't need to factor $x^{31}-1$ completely, just find a factor of degree $5$, which can be done by inspection by trying simple candidates.

Answer (score 2):

There are $\frac{\phi(2^n-1)}{n}$ primitive polynomials of degree $n$ over $GF(2)$. For $n=5$ we have $30/5=6$ primitive polynomials, namely
$$
x^5+x^2+1,\; x^5+x^3+1,\; x^5+x^3+x^2+x+1,\;x^5+x^4+x^2+x+1,\;
$$

$$
x^5+x^4+x^3+x+1,\;x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+1.\;
$$ 
Indeed, the product of all of them, together with the factor $(x+1)$ gives $x^{31}-1$. Using a factorisation algorithm, e.g., the [Berlekamp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp%27s_algorithm) we obtain the factorization of $x^{31}-1$ over $GF(2)$.

Remark: All irreducible polynomials in $GF(2)[x]$ of degree $2, 3, 5$ are 
primitive.

References: See [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimitivePolynomial.html).

Comment: i asked about minimal polynomial

Comment: This is the same as irreducible, monic, and because of $n=5$, the same as primitive (you also asked about primitive).

Comment: can you please tell me how do we get from $x^{5}+x^{2}+1$ to $x^{5}+x^{3}+1$, what factor we are multiplying. Actually i found somewhere written in form $\alpha : m_{1}(x)=x^{5}+x^{3}+1$
then in second row $\alpha ^{3} : m_{3}(x)=x^{5}+x^{4}+x^{3}+x^{2}+1$

Comment: "what factor we are multiplying?" -multiply **all** above factors $(x^5+x^2+1)(x^5+x^3+1)\cdots (x+1)$ together to obtain $x^{31}-1$.